# Update and Insert Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, upsert

I have four tables which constantly truncate then inserts and updates data every five minutes from another system into SQL Server. So I need to create an update and insert trigger to update another in SQL Server using if exists or merge.

```
Select 
[Barcode]
 ,[TradingPartnerOrderNo]
 ,[ProductNo]
 ,[BarcodeCreatedDateTime]
 ,[BarcodeScheduledDateTime]
 ,[CancelledIndicator]
 ,[CancelledDateTime]
 ,[SiteIndicator]
 ,[InterfaceTimeStamp]
 ,[OperationDate]
 ,[Operation]
from [dbo].[BookingView]
```

Comment: Hi! What exactly is your question? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use [`MERGE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx) to do that. Something like this:

```
MERGE INTO table2 AS TGT
USING
(

    Select 
      [Barcode]
     ,[TradingPartnerOrderNo]
     ,[ProductNo]
     ,[BarcodeCreatedDateTime]
     ,[BarcodeScheduledDateTime]
     ,[CancelledIndicator]
     ,[CancelledDateTime]
     ,[SiteIndicator]
     ,[InterfaceTimeStamp]
     ,[OperationDate]
     ,[Operation]
    FROM [dbo].[BookingView]
) AS SRC ON  SRC.Barcode = TGT.BarCode AND
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Barcode, TradingPartnerOrderNo, ...)
  VALUES (SRC.Barcode, SRC.TradingPartnerOrderNo, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it is not very clear your demande but here is a trigger example :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[up_update_mytable]
ON [dbo].[MyTable] FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @ID = ID FROM INSERTED --Use INSERTED keyword for insert and update triggers to get informations of the inserted or updated record.

UPDATE MyOtherTable SET
Column1 = 'test value',
Column2 = 'test value 2'
WHERE OtherTableID = @ID
```

Comment: This is a **bad** example. Triggers fire once per *statement*, and therefore `inserted` (and `deleted`) can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Your trigger obtains the `id` arbitrarily from *one* of those rows and *ignores* the others.